# ¿Cómo se usa bind_param en mysqli? - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

Un post en la web cuenta como realizar un sistema de login con PHP y MySQL. ([Formulario](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/create-a-php-login-form--cms-33261))

La cuestión es que usa el objeto PDO el cual, a mi parecer es mejor que mysqli. Pero todo mi código está escrito en mysqli. Y tendría código basura al establecer en $_GLOBALS conexiones para cada caso, tanto para PDO como para mysqli.

Mi problema específicamente, radica en la función bind_param(). Intenté mudar todo el código e hice cambios tras cambios y no doy con la solución. Es un problema al pasarle los argumentos. El error es el siguiente:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Argument #2 cannot be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\login\register.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\login\register.php on line 21
```

La linea #21: `$query->bind_param('ss', "email", $email);`

```
include('config.php');
session_start();

// // Colocar ésto en cada página que se quiera proteger
// if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
//     header('Location: login.php?unlogged');
//     exit;
// } else {
//     // Mostramos página
// }

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL=email");
    $query->bind_param('ss', "email", $email);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        echo '<p class="error">El email ya está registrado</p>';
    }

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL) VALUES (username,password_hash,email)");
        $query->bind_param('ss', 'username', $username);
        $query->bind_param('ss', 'password_hash', $password_hash);
        $query->bind_param('ss', 'email', $email);
        $result = $query->execute();

        if ($result) {
            echo '<p class="success">Registro exitoso</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Algo salió mal!</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Éste es el original en PDO:

```
include('config.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL=:email");
    $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
    }

    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL) VALUES (:username,:password_hash,:email)");
        $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("password_hash", $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result = $query->execute();

        if ($result) {
            echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas escribir tu consulta utilizando el símbolo '?'

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $email);
```

El método bind_param, asocia el tipo de dato con la variable que estas trabajando. La consulta se compilara más adelante y sustituye a el símbolo '?' por el contenido de $email.

Saludos

Comment: Me sirvió! Mil gracias!